# Drone Flight Controller and Firmware that supports ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, drone, ardupilot, pixhawk

I am a newbie to Drones, I looked into many articles over the internet to find out which flight controller should I use, but not fully able to understand as the cheap flight controllers like speedybee's one does not have any hint that I can use ROS with that and some people are suggesting they have seen people using ROS with only ardupiolot and pixhawk. Any suggestion or link will be much appreciated for clarification.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, most people typically use Pixhawk or ArduPilot when using drones with ROS. While I'm not sure exactly why you want to use SpeedyBee, such flight controllers usually do not officially support ROS.
However, if you still wish to use them, you might be able to gain limited control by intercepting and mocking serial signals on their internal buses. This approach requires a deep understanding of the field, extensive experience, and a highly controlled environment for safety, making it not recommended for drone beginners like yourself.

If gaining control over a flight controller that doesn't officially support ROS isn't the primary goal of your project, it's highly recommended to avoid it.

Although Pixhawk or ArduPilot controllers may seem expensive compared to controllers like SpeedyBee, the cost is unlikely to outweigh the trials, errors, time wastage, and risks associated with not using them.

Below are the official ROS integration links for both controllers for your reference.

https://docs.px4.io/main/en/ros/ros2_comm.html

https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/ros.html

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion